# C# Adding doubles and ints to a list

Tags: c#

Noob logic student here.

How do you add doubles and ints to a list? I still have a hard time reading Microsoft's guide.

```
    public static List<string> salesCustomerName = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> salesItemDescription = new List<string>();
    public static List<double> salesItemPrice = new List<double>();
    public static List<int> salesQuantity = new List<int>();


    public static void ReadItems() {
      // use a StreamReader to read data from items.csv 
      string filename = "data/items.csv";
      if (File.Exists(filename)) {
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename)){
        reader.ReadLine();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
          var line = reader.ReadLine();
          var values = line.Split(",");
          salesCustomerName.Add(values[0]);
          salesItemDescription.Add(values[1]);
          salesItemPrice[2].Add();
          salesQuantity.AddInt();
      }
    }
   } else {
    Console.WriteLine($"{filename} does not exist");
        }
      // populate the items lists
      SaveItems();
```

Comment: What is exactly the issue you are having? Parsing strings as ints or doubles? You need `int.Parse` (if you are sure it won't fail, else `TryParse`), and `double.Parse` (you can also use the `Convert` methods). After that, you simply call `Add` on the corresponding list. And BTW, `salesItemPrice[2].Add()` makes no sense: you are calling `Add` on the third double of that list, double has no `Add` method. Similarly, `List<int>` has no method called `AddInt`. Finally, beware that you are reading and ignoring the first line of the csv (that might be on purpose).

Comment: Not sure what you mean, If you want an int and double are on the same list. Use ArrayList instead of List

Comment: A little new to StackOverFlow, I apologize in advanced. The project that I am tasked with require me to use list, so I cannot use an array. I am also writing data to files using these list.

Comment: This actually works for adding an int to the list: ```salesQuantity.Add(Convert.ToInt32(strQuantity));```

Comment: Do you want something like a `List<int or double>`, I mean a `List` that stores everything? It is possible, but comes along with a huge load of possibe problems...

Comment: @deHaar Right I am mainly aiming for int or double. There was an answer below to add the int to the list I am now testing the following: ```salesItemPrice.Add(Convert.ToDouble(values[3]))``` but currently receiving cs1061.

Comment: @Andrew I am reading the first line of the csv on purpose, to pull the populated data within the CSV. Hope I am making sense lol So, I believe I needed to convert the value to an Int and the next would have to be converted as a double. I am trying ```salesItemPrice.Add(Convert.ToDouble(values[3]))``` but no luck as of now.

Comment: You can use `List<object>`...

Comment: @deHaar Thank you. Turns out I was still using  .AddDouble lol. I updated it and was able to convert to a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as you did with the `salesCustomerName` but you will need to convert into integer and double and add them.

```
salesQuantity.Add(Convert.ToInt32(strQuantity));
```

Similarly for item price, convert to double and add it.

Comment: So basically to add a double it should look like this correct: ```salesItemPrice.Add(Convert.ToDouble(values[3]))```